# How to crop image in 1080x810 resolution in android crop?

Tags: android, android-imageview, crop

I've tried all the things.I need the output image in `4:3` with `1080x810` resolution. It hangs when i use extra high resolution than `500px`.

Comment: use nine patch images

Comment: I am taking camera images and need to crop in 4:3 aspect ration with extra high resolution